# Inverse matrix of (A+aI)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

If I have a known matrix A and its inverse $A^{-1}$, is it possible to calculate $(A+aI)^{-1}$ in terms of the $A^{-1}$, $a$, and $I$, where $I$ is a identical matrix, and a is a number which can be real or complex.

Comment: if $A$ is symmetric, the inverse is $PD^{-1}P^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and the $i$th diagonal element is given by $\lambda_i +a$. Here $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$th eigenvalue. Note that $\lambda_i + a$ must not be zero for all $i$

Comment: In case absolute value of all eigenvalues of A is less than 1, we could write $(A+aI)^{-1}$ as $\frac1a (I-\frac Aa+\frac{A^2}{a^2} - \frac{A^3}{a^3}+\cdots)$

Comment: @ZhaohuiDu Is that the logarithmic expansion? How does that relate to the matrix inverse

Comment: $(I+B)^{-1} = I - B + B^2 - B^3 + \dots$ is just a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
     (A+aI)^{-1}&=(A(I+aA^{-1}))^{-1} \\
         &= (I+aA^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1} \\
         &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^na^n(A^{-1})^{n+1}
\end{align*}
This converges if $|a|\|A^{-1}\| < 1$, for example.